# Scaling images not working properly?

Tags: php, resize, scale, getimagesize

I have a `$this->_tempFile` that holds the temp path of an uploaded image file.

Now I wish to scale an image, it do resizes it but it doesn't scale right. The output is a big black square the bottom at the height and half of the image (width). And i tried with other images, and all turns out being these dimensions:
293px × 453px , why i don't know?

Here's my function for the `scaleImage();`

```
scaleImage(900, 582);

public function scaleImage($width, $height){
    $rel_difference = array('width'=>0, 'height'=>0);
    if($width > 604) $rel_difference['width'] = ($width-604)/604;
    if($height > 453) $rel_difference['height'] = ($height-453)/453;

    asort($rel_difference);
    $tmpname = $this->_tempFile;
    $newwidth = $width/(1+end($rel_difference));
    $newheight = $height/(1+end($rel_difference)); 
    $newwidth = round($newwidth);
    $newheight = round($newheight);
    $jpeg_quality = 90;

    switch(exif_imagetype($tmpname)) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            $img_r = imagecreatefromgif($tmpname);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmpname);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $img_r = imagecreatefrompng($tmpname);
            break;
        default:
            echo json_encode(array('error' => 'Not an image!'));
            exit(0);
            break;
    }
    $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $newwidth, $newheight );

    imagecopyresampled($dst_r, $img_r, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth , $newheight, $width, $height);

    imagejpeg($dst_r,$tmpname,$jpeg_quality);

    }
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: > If the source and destination coordinates and width and heights differ, appropriate stretching or shrinking of the image fragment will be performed. The coordinates refer to the upper left corner. This function can be used to copy regions within the same image (if dst_image is the same as src_image) but if the regions overlap the results will be unpredictable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have accidentally flipped the height and width in the parameters you're passing. So do

```
scaleImage(582, 900);
```

Comment: I did a test using the a slightly modified version of original poster's code and it works perfectly if the width and height are passed properly, but results in the problem described if the original image width is passed as the height (and height as width). So MIKE C is correct.